# Adding a drop-down in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, excel, template

I am the sole GIS manager for an organization of approximately 200 individuals that perform engineering assessments and collect other data to prepare for and respond to natural disasters. Most do not have any GIS experience. My supervisor wants to send them with an ArcMap template that they can fill in as needed. A topographic base map and style sheet are easy enough to send along, but I am wondering if it is possible to include a drop-down menu with preloaded options in the layout mode. The only way I can think of to do this is to use "Insert Object > Excel Document" and include this on the template.

Answer (score 4):

[Adding a domain would create a dropdown.](http://www.exprodat.com/blogs/blog_Tip-5-Geodatabase-Attribute-Domains.htm)

As an alternative to ArcGIS Desktop, I find [ArcGIS Collector App](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/) to be the easiest software for working with field crews for emergency management, it's a quick and easy learning curve and can be set up to collect using a celluar network or offline.  There are already templates available for emergency management, but creating your own to meet your needs is not difficult.

Comment: The question is about arcgis desktop not arcgis server or arcgis online! Your link "Adding a domain would create a dropdown" is not relevant to the quesiton either.

Comment: Updated hyperlink. Pasted a collector link by accident.

Comment: I have been pushing for updating the way we utilize GIS to include Collector and Survey123. Unfortunately as my office is part of the US government, there are restrictions on how I operate: data transfer is done through CDs since I have no internet and can't use USBs, there is no upgrading from 10.0.1.x, etc. I was just looking to see if there was something that I could include on the new template that I'll be sending along with people when they go into the field to conduct their assessments.

Comment: Understood. Domains should help for a regular ArcGIS Desktop license.