# Creating Drop Down Menu in the Attribute File of a Shapefile

Tags: arcmap

I am creating a shapefile template so I can distribute to the province for consultants to fill out. This is to standardize the type of data I will be receiving.

Here is an example of the type of content I want in an attribute:

Wetland Class:

- Bog
  -Fen
  Swamp
  -marsh

Is there a way to make a dropdown menu for this feature that lists the following options to chose from? I wanted to keep it to a shapefile and steer away from using a geodatabase if possible. I am using ArcMap.

Comment: Shapefiles are approaching 30 years old, and use a database spec which is a decade older. The functionality you want is an intrinsic part of file geodatabase (and has been for decades). Shapefile is not an option here.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444908/making-drop-down-menus-for-shapefiles

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a drop-down in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175162/adding-a-drop-down-in-arcmap)

Comment: Totally agree with @Vince, shapefiles are not a smart choice, a geodatabase is a far more powerful storage format and from a users perspective almost no difference in how you interact with them. By using a geodatabase you can build into your workflow so many more data quality improvements. So the look up lists you are asking for are called Domains and guess what shapefiles can't use them...

Comment: @hornybydd thanks! It's just I know other consultants that I may provide this template to may not have access to Arcmap and may use QGIS. I have been having issues using geodatabases on QGIS so I was just trying to find a more universal option.